# Find unmatched list from directory files in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file called samples.list with sample IDs. I have same files in my directory that I want to pattern match with my sample.list and get the output of unmatched sample.list.

samples.list

```
SRR1369385 
SRR1352799
SRR1377262
SRR1400622
```

ls -lh

```
-rw-rw----+ 1 gen dbgap_6109 2.2G Jul 29 02:44 SRR1369385_1.fastq.gz 
-rw-rw----+ 1 gen dbgap_6109 2.2G Jul 29 02:44 SRR1369385_2.fastq.gz 
-rw-rw----+ 1 gen dbgap_6109 1.2G Jul 29 03:34 SRR1352799_1.fastq.gz 
-rw-rw----+ 1 gen dbgap_6109 1.2G Jul 29 03:34 SRR1352799_2.fastq.gz 
-rw-rw----+ 1 gen tnt_pipeli 2.2G Jul 29 01:44 sometxt.txt
```

The output I want (samples that did not match with the file names in the directory):

```
SRR1377262
SRR1400622
```

code I tried:

```
grep -oFf `cat samples.list` ls -lh | grep -vFf - `cat samples.list`
```

I would really appreciate if someone could guide me through the solution.

Comment: [do not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: @KamilCuk  I tried, but won't work: grep -oFf \`cat samples.list`  $(ls -1q | tr " " "?") | grep -vFf - \`cat samples.list`

Comment: Do not parse ls. Forget ls exists. `ls` is for pretty printing files in your terminal. If you are in a script, do not use `ls`. The lines you are trying `grep -oFf cat samples.list $(ls -1q | tr " " "?") | grep -vFf - cat samples.list` make very little sense, I suggest rather to re-read the relevant man pages. : / I advise, do not "guess" programming, rather first read then try.

Comment: Run `join -v2 <(f=(*_*.fastq.gz); IFS=$'\n'; echo "${f[*]%%_*}" | uniq) <(sort -u /path/to/samples.list)` in the directory where the SRR*.fastq.gz files reside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# find all files named in the way you want and print filenames
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*_*.fastq.gz' -printf "%f\n" |
# Remove all everything except the SRR=numbers
sed 's/_.*//' |
# Sort the list, remove duplicate elements
sort -u |
# join the list with samples and print only unmatched elements from samples
join -v1 -o 1.1 <(sort samples.list) -
```

[Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/DefiantMatureWeb#main.sh).

Notes:

- do not use backticks `. Prefer `$(...)` instead. [obsolete and deprecated syntax bashhackers wiki](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete)
- `grep`s `-f` options takes *filename* not content of the file. You could do `grep -f some_file.txt` to grep with all regexes stored in `some_file.txt`.
- `ls -lh` produces output to `stdout`. Running `grep ls -lh` would make `grep` want to search file named `ls` (and what for `-l` and `-h` if you want to search filenames?). While you could `ls -1 | grep`, but it's better to `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 | grep ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F_ 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next}!($0 in a)' <(ls) samples.list
```

First that will index everything until `_` from `ls` for each output line (`NR==FNR` is true for these lines), and then find all unmatched lines in `samples.list` (»if a line is not indexed, print it«).